# make a div move and rebound when reached the edges of the container

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a `div` move and rebound once reached the edges of the container `div` i'm using this code to do so but the debugger display's this error `Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined`

```
var speed = 10,
     direction = 1;

     var ballElement = document.getElementsByClassName('ball'),
         containerElement = document.getElementsByClassName('mainDiv');
     if (ballElement) {
        var boxLeftPos = ballElement.offsetLeft,
            boxRightPos = boxLeftPos + ballElement.offsetWidth;

            if (boxRightPos > document.containerElement.offsetWidth) {
                direction = -1;
            }

            if (boxLeftPos < 0) {
                direction = 1;
            }

            ballElement.style.left = (boxLeftPos + speed * direction) + 'px';
     }
```

the error is in this line :

```
if (boxRightPos > document.containerElement.offsetWidth)
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9Lsooq8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array. If you have only one element of that class, add [0] to retrieve it: `getElementsByClassName('ball')[0]`

remove `document.` from `if (boxRightPos > document.containerElement.offsetWidth) {`

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7rw1t8eh/

Answer (score 1):

`document.containerElement` is undefined it should just be `containerElement` by the looks of it

Answer (score 1):

The result of `document.getElementsByClassName` is a `nodeList` object. So, it has no offsetWidth or style. You could use `document.querySelector('.ball')` instead, or use `containerElement[0]`.